# Alphabet and code ascii

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program in c language that gets a number and a string, for example the number is 3 and the string is "Zig". 
The output should be alphabet's codes + the number. If the character's number goes more than "Z" (90) it should start from "A" again. Similarily, for lower case characters, when going beyond "z" start again from "a".
input  : "Zig"
number : 3
output : "Clj"
I have a problem with the part that it should start from A(for capitals) & a again.
this is my code now ! I have a problem with rotation part how to start from A or a again :)

```
char a[50];

int n,i;
printf("enter your number:\t");

scanf("%d",&n);
printf("enter your string:\t");

fflush(stdin);

gets(a);

while('A'<= a[i] <= 'Z'){
    if(a[i]+n > 'Z'){

    }
    else{
    a[i]=a[i]+n;
}
i++;
}
while('a' <= a[i] <= 'z'){
    if(a[i]+n > 'z'){

}
    else{
        a[i]=a[i]+n;
    }
    i++;
}
printf("string:\n");
puts(a);
```

}

Comment: You need to put some effort in writing your question. As it stands here nobody understands what you want.

Comment: well i said that we get a number and a string like the string is Zig and the number is 3 the output should be Clj ! for example A (65) + 3(the number) = D(68)

Comment: Please show the code which only has the problem of doing the rotation part. I understand that it works as long the letter value is smaller than `('Z'-n)` or `('z'-n)`.

Comment: please add any relevant information to the question by using the "edit" button. thabks!

Comment: I edited my question take a look at it :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed Bug

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>


int main(){
  char str [80];
  int number;

  printf ("Enter your string: ");
  scanf ("%79s",str);  


  printf ("Enter your number: ");
  scanf ("%d",&number);

  for(int i= 0; i < strlen(str);i++){
    str[i]+=number;
    while(str[i]>'Z' && str[i] < 'a'){
        str[i] = 'A'+ str[i] - 'Z';
    }
    while(str[i]>'z'){
        str[i] = 'a'+ str[i] - 'z';
    }
  }

  printf("%s",str);

}
```

Comment: no cause if u enter your string Zig and  your number 3 it gives u ]lj , it should give back Clj

Comment: yessss it doessss thank you :)) can you describe it please :)

Comment: I fixed another bug but it basically just finds the difference that it overflows from 'Z' and adds it to 'A' creating a loop. p.s please accept my answer if you want lol.

Comment: sorry but it still has a small problem , like if the word is capital like N + 20 should be I but it shows b :(

Comment: yesss it does :))) can you explain why you put 'A' + a[i] - 'Z'

Comment: It may help to think of the range 'A' to 'Z' in the ascii table as an array where 'A' is the 0th index and 'Z' is the last index. Assuming str[i] is greater than the last index ('Z'), you subtract the difference between the two and that gives you how far over the acceptable range you went. All you do then is add that difference that you went over to the 0th index ('A') in order to simulate a loop. 'A' + (str[i] - 'Z') might be a clearer way to show what's happening

Comment: Do you know a code that shows that there is no difference between capital letters and small letters , I mean if u gives the program w and W it thinks both of them are the same ?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a problem with the part that it should start from A(for capitals) & a again

When you get to Z (decimal 90) you can easily subtract 25 (ASCII char "EM") to get back to A (decimal 65). Similarly you can repeat subtraction of 25 when you reach z and it will cycle back to

Comment: Do you know a code that shows that there is no difference between capital letters and small letters , I mean if u gives the program w and W it thinks both of them are the same ?

Comment: You could convert all lowercase to uppercase by subtracting 32 and leave the uppercase as is. That way all uppercase letters would represent either itself or it’s lowercase equivalent.